# Uncaught Error: `reducer` is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm building a React and Node.js app. In the frontend, in the src folder, there's a folder called store that contains a file called index.js that calls the root reducer

index.js

```js
import { configureStore, applyMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const store = configureStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))

export default store
```

The reducer code is in a file called index.js in a folder called reducers inside the store folder

reducer code

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from "./auth";

export default combineReducers({
  // auth: authReducer  This did not work either
  authReducer
})
```

The terminal in vscode says webpack compiled successfully.
The browser displays a white screen and the console says the following

```
configureStore.ts:106 Uncaught Error: `reducer` is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers
    at configureStore (configureStore.ts:106:1)
    at ./src/store/index.js (index.js:5:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at ./src/index.js (Chat.js:17:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Redux-Toolkit's [`configureStore`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore) takes a single configuration object instead of an array of parameters like the older deprecated legacy `createStore`. The parameters are `reducer`, `middleware`, `devTools`, `preloadedState`, and `enhancers` (*see [Parameters](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#parameters) for details*).

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});
```

Redux-Toolkit also ships with Thunk middleware included and enabled by default, so there's no need to explicitly import `Thunk` and include it in the middleware.

If you needed to configure and/or add middleware, use the [`getDefaultMiddleware`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware) utility.

Example:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware(
    /* configure default middleware */
  )
    .concat(/* append any additional middleware here */)
    .prepend(/* prepend any additional middleware here */)
});
```

Or if you really just don't want any of the default middleware and just want to specify the middleware directly, pass an array.

Example:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [thunk],
});
```